# plugin for adding issues referring to manual rules into sonar

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

```
 import org.sonar.api.component.ResourcePerspectives;

       public class MySensor extends Sensor {
         private final ResourcePerspectives perspectives;

         public MySensor(ResourcePerspectives p) {
           this.perspectives = p;
         }

         public void analyse(Project project, SensorContext context) {
           Resource myResource; // to be set
           Issuable issuable = perspectives.as(Issuable.class, myResource);
           if (issuable != null) {
             // can be used
             Issue issue = issuable.newIssueBuilder()
               //repository : pmd, key : AvoidArrayLoops
               .setRuleKey(RuleKey.of("pmd", "AvoidArrayLoops"))
               .setLine(10)
               .build();
             //works
             issuable.addIssue(issue);
             Issue issue2 = issuable.newIssueBuilder()
               //repository : manual, key : performance
               .setRuleKey(RuleKey.of("manual", "performance"))
               .setLine(10)
               .build();
             // doesn't work
             issuable.addIssue(issue2);
           }
         }
       }
```

When I try to add the issue "issue" referring to the pmd rule AvoidArrayLoops it works. More generally, when I try to add issues referring to pmd or checkstyle rules it works.

However, when I try to add issues referring to manual rules such as the issue "issue2", it doesn't work. I have created manually the rule "performance" so the rule performance exists in the list of manual rules in sonar.

I would like to know if it is impossible to add issues referring to manual rules or if I am not using the right parameters for the method RuleKey.of.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One reason why your custom issue is not shown in Sonar may be that you haven't enabled it the rule.

Select settings - Quality Profiles, click on your quality profile, select the tab "Coding rules", set Activation to "any", click search and check whether your rule is being displayed here.

If so, check the checkbox next to it and select the severity. Now, the rule violations will be displayed in Sonar.